# Jquery ui dialog Maximized by default

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i want Jquery ui dialog to be maximized by default  without giving and height and width or else can we give height and width pixel dynamically according screen size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then use [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) event in jQuery/Which will fire when the window size is changed

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var width1= $(window).width();
    var width2= width1* 0.9;
    var height1= $(window).height();
    var height2= height1* 0.9;
    $("#dialog-id").dialog("option", "width", width2);
    $("#dialog-id").dialog("option", "height", height2);
});
```